How to predict the efficiency of a very low speed Railgun Actuator/Lorentz Force Actuator?
Well, I read somewhere that the slower the railgun is, the higher its efficiency, so I started trying to find out what would be the efficiency of a railgun actuator to move a heavy object (3000kg) at very low speeds (around 2 m/s).
Since the railgun works by using lorentz force, I tried to find rail lorentz force actuators, but I could only find voice coils actuators, and whenever I search for those, their efficiency is below 1%.
I also asked ChatGPT on how to calculate it, and it said that I should use the equaton for energy input and energy output to calculate the efficiency of the system, but how I can calculate the energy input without an actual system?

Energy input = 1/2 * C * V^2, where C is the capacitance and V is the
voltage.

Then it showed me that a lorentz force actuator that pushes a 3000kg mass at 2m/s of speed would be:

1/2 x 0.333 Capacitance x (200)² voltage = 6666.67 J


GPT knows nothing of technical topics -- fundamentally it is an algorithm to produce plausible text; that it has any meaning at all is pure coincidence, there is no semantic knowledge implemented (at least at this time).

@TimWilliams Yeah, but I always try chatgpt first just to see if my questions have an obvious answer so I don't bother other people online
